# Echoing variable results

Tags: php

I'm just learning php from a book and I'm doing one of the exercises where the purpose is to create a grade calculator. I'm trying to have the grade echoed out under the form and I'm having trouble.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

    <form method="post">
        <label>Assignment 1:</label><input type="text" name="assignmentOne" value="0"></br>

        <label>Assignment 2:</label><input type="text" name="assignmentTwo" value="0"></br>

        <label>Assignment 3:</label><input type="text" name="assignmentThree" value="0"></br>

        <label>Assignment 4:</label><input type="text" name="assignmentFour" value="0"></br>

        <label>Assignment 5:</label><input type="text" name="assignmentFive" value="0"></br>

        <label>Assignment 6:</label><input type="text" name="assignmentSix" value="0"></br>

        <label>Final Project:</label><input type="text" name="finalProject" value="0"></br>

        <label>Final Exam:</label><input type="text" name="finalExam" value="0"></br>

        <input type="button" name="calculate" value="Calculate Grade"></br>
    </form>

        <?php
            if ($_POST) {
                    $assignmentOne = $_POST['assignmentOne'];
                    $assignmentTwo = $_POST['assignmentTwo'];
                    $assignmentThree = $_POST['assignmentThree'];
                    $assignmentFour = $_POST['assignmentFour'];
                    $assignmentFive = $_POST['assignmentFive'];
                    $assignmentSix = $_POST['assignmentSix'];
                    $finalProject = $_POST['finalProject'];
                    $finalExam = $_POST['finalExam'];

                    $grade = (((assignmentOne + assignmentTwo + assignmentThree + assignmentFour + assignmentFive + assignmentSix) / 6)* .50) + (finalProject * .30) + (finalExam * .20);
                echo "Final Grade $grade";
            }   
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, what sort of trouble are you having?

Comment: Change `$_POST['finalExam'];` to `$_POST['FinalExam'];` or change the name of the final input to `finalExam`

Comment: ^^ Variables and array keys are case sensitive in PHP.

Comment: Hint: Variables in Php are prefixed with a $.  A variable named $foo can not be referred to as foo.

Comment: If you are new to Php you will need to learn how to debug.  It really helps to be able to read errors to identify problems.  Read about error reporting in Php.

Comment: Like Progrock said... before you start anything you really should research how to read and display errors. It will save you countless hours of time in the future if you get PHP to tell you what is wrong instead of having to post here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

    <form method="post" action="info.php">
        <label>Assignment 1:</label><input type="text" name="assignmentOne" value="0"></br>

        <label>Assignment 2:</label><input type="text" name="assignmentTwo" value="0"></br>

        <label>Assignment 3:</label><input type="text" name="assignmentThree" value="0"></br>

        <label>Assignment 4:</label><input type="text" name="assignmentFour" value="0"></br>

        <label>Assignment 5:</label><input type="text" name="assignmentFive" value="0"></br>

        <label>Assignment 6:</label><input type="text" name="assignmentSix" value="0"></br>

        <label>Final Project:</label><input type="text" name="finalProject" value="0"></br>

        <label>Final Exam:</label><input type="text" name="FinalExam" value="0"></br>

        <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Calculate Grade"></br>
    </form>

    <?php
    if ($_POST) {

        $assignmentOne = $_POST['assignmentOne'];
        $assignmentTwo = $_POST['assignmentTwo'];
        $assignmentThree = $_POST['assignmentThree'];
        $assignmentFour = $_POST['assignmentFour'];
        $assignmentFive = $_POST['assignmentFive'];
        $assignmentSix = $_POST['assignmentSix'];
        $finalProject = $_POST['finalProject'];
        $finalExam = $_POST['finalExam'];

        $grade = ((($assignmentOne + $assignmentTwo + $assignmentThree + $assignmentFour + $assignmentFive + $assignmentSix) / 6)* 0.50) + ($finalProject * .30) + ($finalExam * .20);
        echo "Final Grade $grade";
    }
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

try this will help

Answer (score 0):

Your form needed a submit button and an action attribute. Also your variables were not written correctly.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

        <form method="post" action="">
            <label>Assignment 1:</label><input type="text" name="assignmentOne" value="0"></br>

            <label>Assignment 2:</label><input type="text" name="assignmentTwo" value="0"></br>

            <label>Assignment 3:</label><input type="text" name="assignmentThree" value="0"></br>

            <label>Assignment 4:</label><input type="text" name="assignmentFour" value="0"></br>

            <label>Assignment 5:</label><input type="text" name="assignmentFive" value="0"></br>

            <label>Assignment 6:</label><input type="text" name="assignmentSix" value="0"></br>

            <label>Final Project:</label><input type="text" name="finalProject" value="0"></br>

            <label>Final Exam:</label><input type="text" name="finalExam" value="0"></br>

            <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Calculate Grade"></br>
        </form>

        <?php
            if ($_POST) {
                    $assignmentOne = $_POST['assignmentOne'];
                    $assignmentTwo = $_POST['assignmentTwo'];
                    $assignmentThree = $_POST['assignmentThree'];
                    $assignmentFour = $_POST['assignmentFour'];
                    $assignmentFive = $_POST['assignmentFive'];
                    $assignmentSix = $_POST['assignmentSix'];
                    $finalProject = $_POST['finalProject'];
                    $finalExam = $_POST['finalExam'];

                    $grade = ((($assignmentOne + $assignmentTwo + $assignmentThree + $assignmentFour + $assignmentFive + $assignmentSix) / 6)* .50) + ($finalProject * .30) + ($finalExam * .20);
                echo "Final Grade $grade";

            }   
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
```